# how would I use HAProxy to return a 400 error based on unencoded characters in the URL?

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I would like to write a haproxy rule that would return a 400 bad request error message when the url contains unencoded characters. These bad characters are causing server errors in my application and eventually an out-of-memory error, and it'd be great to head them off at the pass.

The right way (I know) is to fix this on the server side, but for a lot of dumb reasons I can't change that code right now.

I think I need something like

```
acl bad_char path_reg [(badcharsethere)]
```

but I can't find examples of what redirecting to the 400 error would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a fake back-end, and configure its 503 (Service Unavailable) static HTTP response file to point to the file you'll use as a canned response, then use that back-end to serve those requests.  The error code the client sees is determined only by what's in the static file.  Copy one of the example error files and remember that they are raw HTTP responses, so you need `\r\n` at the end of each header and a `\r\n\r\n` at the end of the headers.

```
use_backend bogus if bad_char

backend bogus
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/400badchar.http
```

When the ACL is matched, HAProxy will try to use the bogus back-end, which has no servers, so HAProxy will try to return a 503, which will return your custom response file, which you will have modified to return a custom 400 error.

Comment: I'm glad you like it.  P.S. you should really fix your server. :)  But it occurred to me that there's another potentially cool option, using Lua in HAProxy 1.6... you could write a small Lua function to replace the bogus characters and return a redirect to the browser or with the "corrected" URI in the `Location:` header.  Or you could massage the request with Lua's `string.gsub()` and then HAProxy would forward it to the server in the "corrected" form.

Comment: That's a good idea. :-) (Both the fix-the-server and the Lua replace function.)

Comment: And I had forgotten about the new [`regsub` converter](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#7.3.1-regain) ... lots of good stuff in HAProxy 1.6.